# Internationalization/localization of data in Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am experimenting with Parse for creating the backend for my application and I need to support localized data.

I can't be the first one that tries to do that, but I am unable to find anything about it. I was thinking of keeping the data like this:

```
// Post class
{
    "title": {
        "en": "Good morning!",
        "de": "Guten Tag!"  
    },
    // Other properties
}
```

But then the queries would need to be targeted specifically against a localization on the client side since you can't query the title property directly. So I need to do some client side magic first. Does it seem like a bad way to do it? Have this been solved better?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. this is a confusing question. Are you asking how to go about and add localization to your app? http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Comment: Didn't you read my question? I am stating that I am using Parse and I wonder how to add localization for my data.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Parse itself, but I'm upvoting because it's a general problem that still doesn't have 'the perfect solution'. Just know that Parse doesn't have anything special with localization.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what the data is and how it's being added / updated. I wouldn't use a dictionary with multiple keys like that, I'd either use different objects with a language column so I could query for just the language I want or I'd have multiple language specific columns so I could include only what I want. The former is easier to manage and likely more efficient in the long run.